# HTML CSS: text won't fill the div horizontally in Android 4.3

Tags: html, css, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a problem accessing my website with and Android device using Jelly Bean 4.3. The *div* containing the text is not filled horizontally (less than half of it) but only if `text-align` is set to *left* (as it should). If set to *center*, it is filled but it looks ugly.

This is my `h4` CSS definition:

```
h4
{
    text-align: left;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 180%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

Which could be the cause ?

Comment: Might be helpful to provide a bit more code.. maybe the text that is in question. Better yet, make a fiddle of the code.

Comment: Try using `box-sizing: border-box;` on the element .The padding may be pushing the content down.

Comment: @hopkins-matt: the text is just a normal text and a fiddle would be hard as I create the site dynamically via PHP. I'll write it to a file and post it as soon as I've time

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall: doesn't fix but thanks for the try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a real HTML expert but I'm pretty sure it's a bug.

I have no idea why, but if I add a color to `background-color` it works.

Not `transparent`, `inherit` or `initial` but a real color otherwise it doesn't work. Since the parent div has a

`background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(230,230,230,0.7), rgba(240,240,255,0.8), rgba(230,230,230,0.7));`,

setting a color makes all look ugly so I added a

`background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(230,230,230,0.0), rgba(240,240,255,0.0), rgba(230,230,230,0.0));`

to the `h4` and it looks perfect, transparent background and div filled with text.

So the `h4` is now:

```
h4
{
   text-align: left;
   width: 90%;
   font-size: 180%;
   font-style: normal;
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   padding: 10px 40px;
   background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(230,230,230,0.0), rgba(240,240,255,0.0), rgba(230,230,230,0.0));
}
```

I hope this helps someone with the same wierd problem.